# Completion of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Theorem 10.1, p.52 of Lang's book on Algebra proves that $\hat{R}_I=\varprojlim_n R/I^n$ is ring ismorphic to Cauchy sequences modulo null sequences, he calls the latter the completion with respect to a non-zero ideal $I$. Here is my question, how can we prove that $\varprojlim_n R/I^n$ is complete in the analysis sense using this theorem proved in Lang. I mean how can we show that every cauchy sequence converges to a limit in $\varprojlim_n R/I^n$? Limit is itself a sequence, so we need a sequence of sequences, and this has confused me quite a bit. As done in analysis, it would be more helpful if someone can show me how this can be achieved by making use of the theorem proved in Lang, which i am comfortable with.

Remark: The above theorem is proved in the setting of groups in Lang but oI can prove it in the above setting.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the diagonal sequence. A sequence of sequences can be represened as $a_{mk}$. let $b_n = a_{nn}$

Comment: This is something i have struggled with also. Can you provide more details? I do not follow your answer. Suppose I take a cauchy sequence in $S$=Cauchy sequences/null sequences, so my sequence looks like $(a_1n, a_2n,...,..)$, where $a_mn\in S$. Now i want to show that this sequence converges to a point in $S$. Do you mean to say that $a_mk$ converges to $b_n$? Can you give some more details? Thanks